# Conditional probability: question on a given solution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

I'm trying to understand the following conditional probability problem and solution from [this page Example 1.19](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter1/1_4_0_conditional_probability.php) and it follows the questions here.

Questions:

1. What is the sample space?  Is it the same for the entire solution?  I can't see how the numbers of the elementary events in the sample space add up to 1 in this solution.
2. The problem seeks to answer to $P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3)$, which is $.8560$.  How would these elementary events intersect to provide such an answer?
3. I have been told that each event here where a unit is chosen is independent from the previous events, so there is no conditional probability in occurring here and in the solution is $P(A|B) = P(A)$ or $P(A \cap B) = P(A) P(B)$.  Is this true?  I have considered this might be true since computing $P(A_2|A_1)= P(A_2 \cap A_1)/P(A_1)$ does not yield the results in the solution.
4. Should I be considering a different approach vs these questions?

> In a factory there are 100 units of a certain product, 5 of which are
> defective. We pick three units from the 100 units at random. What is
> the probability that none of them are defective?
>
> Let us define $A_i$ as the event that the $i$th chosen unit is not
> defective, for $i = 1, 2, 3$.  We are interested in $P(A_1 \cap A_2
> > \cap A_3)$.
>
> $P(A_1) = 95/100$
>
> Given that the first chosen item was good, the second item will be
> chosen from 94 good units and 5 defective units, thus:
>
> $P(A_2|A_1) = 94/99$
>
> Given that the first and second chosen items were okay, the third item
> will be chosen from 93 good units and 5 defective units, tus:
>
> $P(A_3|A_2, A_1) = 93/98$
>
> Thus:
>
> $P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3) = P(A_1)P(A_2|A_1)P(A_3|A_2, A_1)$
>
> $ = 95/100 * 94/99 * 93/98 = 0.8560$

Comment: This is a sample without replacement so the events are not independent

Comment: @Henry if events are not independent, how can one explain the solution.  The solution looks like $P(A|B) = P(A)$, i.e. $95/100, 94/99, ...$.  It does not look like $P(A|B) = P(A \cap B)/P(B)$ has been used.  Thanks

Comment: $\frac 95/100$ is a simple probability while $94/99$ and $93/98$ are conditional probabilities.  This uses $P(A \cap B \cap C)= P(A) P(B \mid A) P(C \mid A \cap B)$

Comment: What I'm getting confused about is $P(B|A) = P(A \cap B)/P(A)$.  Does the intersection $A \cap B$ need to be calculated?  I'm trying to calculate the formula but it seems the solution just treat $P(B|A)$ as $P(B)$ for example.

Comment: $P(B)=95/100$ if you have no information about $A$, while $P(B\mid A)=94/99$  if you know $A$ has happened.  So $P(A \cap B)= \frac{95}{100} \times \frac{94}{99}$

Comment: @Henry for $P(A_2|A_1)$, doesn't $A_1$ set essentially a new sample space?  I don't see that happening, because $|A_1| = 95$, yet the result is $94/99$.  Thanks

Comment: What do you think is the sample space for "In a factory there are 100 units of a certain product, 5 of which are defective. We pick three units from the 100 units at random"?  One possibility is the ${100 \choose 5}$ possibilities for labelling the defectives multiplied by the $100 \times 99 \times 98$ of selecting three items in succession without replacement.  So $73043951904000$ equally likely possibilities.  $A_1$ represents $95\%$ of these so $69391754308800$ possibilities, and given $A_1$ the other $3652197595200$ have a conditional probability of $0$

Comment: Incidentally, using sample spaces here is not particularly useful or revealing